# mule able to modify json output datamapper

Tags: mule

I'm trying convert to csv to json format using mule datamapper ,it is working fine.

below output it produce

```
[ {

  "propertyState" : "AL",
  "propertyCity" : "NJ",
  "propertyZipCode" : "67890",
  "propertyCounty" : "US"

} ]
```

But  want to remove [ ] this from json format. using datamapper is it possible

mule modify  json output  datamapper

Comment: These brackets mean a list of lines of that csv; you will need them if it has more lines. Why do you want to remove them?

Comment: In mule  I want json format output without these  [ ]  because ,i need to pass this as input to external system

Comment: When you defined the mapping for the json output, did you select List<Element>? If you want to output just one element, you can just select Element. HTH

Answer (score 0):

`[]` defines List for the elements .. That is required if your elements are repeating and a Valid **JSON** format ..

If you don't want the `[]` to be there then the work around will be use  `<json:json-to-object-transformer  returnClass="java.util.List" doc:name="JSON to List" />` to extract each elements value from the **JSON** payload and create your payload using **expression** ..

But again this is **not** a recommended approach since you always require `[]` in your JSON as you will be getting multiple rows from **CSV** file and the **JSON** format should have `[]` since that will represent it as **List** which is a valid format